# Android network provider and gps provider handling

Tags: android, gps-time

I have done this code where I ask for updates on location.I want to know if i implemented it correctly. Once page is opened, i request for updates ( preference to network over gps)...and i display the location in function onlocationchanged. I want to ask is it possible inside onlocationchanged i get location null similar when i do getlastknownlocation? 
i stopped using ghetlastknownlocation as it returns nulll at times and wrong values.

> ```
>       boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
>     boolean  isNetworkEnabled = lm
>             .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
>     if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
>     {   
>         ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
>         progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>         Utilities.showAlertDialog2(RegionalStoresMeActivity.this, "", ""+getResources().getString(R.string.nothing_enabled), false);
>     }
>     else if(isNetworkEnabled){
>         // lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, this);       
>         lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
>     }
>     else if(isGPSEnabled ) {                                                                                      
>                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1,0, this);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onLocationChanged() method is only called when their is a location update with the appropriate Latitude and Longitude. It might be null to slightest possibility but I've never experienced it.

U've done it properly but I'll like to make a suggestion. 
Consider a scenario-

The network provider is enabled and u've requested location updates. But for some reason it does not returns location update (there r many cases in which Location provider dosen't return location update also it is not compulsory to return the location updates. )

Now as per ur code it won't check the GPS provider cos its in "else if( isGPSEnabled )". So I'll suggest u to implement it in only "if" statement like below

```
if( isNetworkEnabled )
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, this);

if( isGPSEnabled )                                                                                      
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1,0, this);
```

Comment: ok thx. do not onlocation changed i am doing locationmanager.removeupdates

Comment: if u do locationmanager.removeupdates then it stops listening to location updates.

Comment: i only need it once, when it opens the page.

Comment: then u r goin right. Once u get the location update u can immediately  stop listening for further location updates